# Android GridView scale type similar to html contain

Tags: android, image, android-gridview, scaletype

I have a gridview with 3 columns. I want the images to be scaled so that the entire image is displayed in each gridview cell, even if that means leaving blank space at the top/bottom (landscape) or sides (portrait). The effect should be similar to html [`background-size:contain`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

Incidentally, no matter which scale type I pick, except `FIT-XY`, the pictures, which as all wider than tall, appear as overlapping each other. In `FIT-XY`, the pictures are cropped and then stretched to fill. And I have no idea how the crop is being chosen. I would have thought `FIT-XY` would have just stretched and fitted the entire picture.

Shown below is FIT-CENTER. The image of the truck at the bottom is the full image shown in an imageview from clicking on a gridview item. I would like the gridview to display the full image.

[image]

Also, here is FIT-XY:

[image]

```
activity_main.xml:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.carrentalapp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:numColumns="3" 
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:padding="5dp"> 
    </GridView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ImageAdapter.getView:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "in get view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  thumbnail = new ImageView(context);
  thumbnail.setImageResource(image_ids[position]);
  thumbnail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
  thumbnail.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(188,200));
  return thumbnail;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale type you want is indeed `FIT_CENTER`.

It looks like your `ImageViews` are bigger than you want, and hence are the cause of your issue. Check your `ImageView` width/height values, and if those seem correct (you probably want `match_parent`), then check your `GridView` column widths.

**Edit:**

Change your lines:

```
thumbnail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
thumbnail.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(188,200));
```

To:

```
thumbnail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
thumbnail.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,200));
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Only the bottom is an imageview. I would prefer to not set a specific column width because it should scale with display size. The idea is a gallery where when you click on an item it appears full size in the imageview. Can you explain?  Thanks

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to get what you are saying.  I should post some code.

Comment: OK!  That did it. Just one thing: GridView.LayoutParams takes two int arguments, so the answer was to use `GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.Match_Parent, 50)`. The code said CENTER, but the pictures were really FIT-CENTER.